# Interactivity with server and client in json

Tags: php, html, json

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="vpic"><img src="" width="800" /></div>
    <div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px; cursor:pointer" class="cpic"><img src="" width="200" /></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px; cursor:pointer" class="cpic"><img src="" width="200" /></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px; cursor:pointer" class="cpic"><img src="" width="200" /></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
         console.log("connected");
         $.post("get.php",{},function(shilpa,status){

                 alert("status"+status);
                },"json");

        });



    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**//get.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
var user= <?php echo json_encode(array("data"=>array(
    "father" => array(1,2,3),
    "mother" => array(1,2,3),
    "kid" => array(1,2,3)
))); ?>
</script>
<title>try</title>
</head>
```

I am new in json I want to print json data which is coming from get.php but nothing is back when I am writing this code.

Comment: Do you print json from the `get.php` file?

Comment: Can you show us your `get.php` source code is it `echo json_encode($data);` or something ?

Answer (score 0):

get.php should just print JSON data:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("data" => array(
        "father" => array(1,2,3),
        "mother" => array(1,2,3),
        "kid" => array(1,2,3)
    )));
?>
```